# Using local variables in cl-loop

Tags: elisp-macros, local-variables, cl-lib

This is my first time trying to write my own elisp code, so bear with me. I have the following `cl-loop`:

`data` contains the following:

```
((refs . [((file . "api/user.js") (start . 266) (end . 269)) ((file . "api/user.js") (start . 292) (end . 295)) ((file . "api/user.js") (start . 304) (end . 307)) ((file . "api/user.js") (start . 320) (end . 323)) ((file . "api/user.js") (start . 554) (end . 557)) ((file . "api/user.js") (start . 575) (end . 578))]) (type . "local") (name . "req"))
```

```
  (cl-loop for ref across (cdr (assq 'refs data))
           for start = (1+ (cdr (assq 'start ref))) and
           file = (expand-file-name (cdr (assq 'file ref)) (tern-project-dir))
           if (string= buffer-file-name file)
           if (let ((a 1))
                (print ref)
                (print start)
                (< start (point)))
           collect start into prev-refs
           else collect start into next-refs
           finally return (list file (sort prev-refs '>) (sort next-refs '<)))
```

which currently outputs the following:

> ((file . "api/user.js") (start . 266) (end . 269))
>
> 267
>
> ((file . "api/user.js") (start . 292) (end . 295))
>
> 267
>
> ((file . "api/user.js") (start . 304) (end . 307))
>
> 293
>
> ((file . "api/user.js") (start . 320) (end . 323))
>
> 305
>
> ((file . "api/user.js") (start . 554) (end . 557))
>
> 321
>
> ((file . "api/user.js") (start . 575) (end . 578))
>
> 555

This seems to be close, but I don't understand why `start` stays the same for the first 2 iterations of the loop (causing it to miss the `start` value in the last iteration). What I'm hoping to do is to define the variables to be used within the loop.

I've tried using `with` instead of the second `for`, but that didn't work. I've gotten it to work by using the full code for `start` and `file` in the various places where they're used, but that produces some quite ugly code.

btw, I just added that `let` statement only so I could execute those `print` statements.

Any help on getting the desired outcome would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to `bpalmer` in `#emacs` for helping me solve this. The issue was with the `and` after `for start...`; instead, it needed to be another `for` (or `as`). I chose to use `as` instead of the other `for`s since it seems a bit more intuitive, but either will work.

The correct code is:

```
  (cl-loop for ref across (cdr (assq 'refs data))
           as start = (1+ (cdr (assq 'start ref)))
           as file = (expand-file-name (cdr (assq 'file ref)) (tern-project-dir))
           if (string= buffer-file-name file)
           if (let ((a 1))
                (print ref)
                (print start)
                (< start (point)))
           collect start into prev-refs
           else collect start into next-refs
           finally return (list file (sort prev-refs '>) (sort next-refs '<)))
```